# k-means cluster analysis for pitch curves in r

Tags: r, k-means

so I have many pitch curves time normalized.
I though of using k-means as tool for automatically cluster these.
I have the hypothesis that they correlate to three patterns but I
want to go for an exploratory way.

This is (a piece of) my data frame

```
time            1       2       3       4       5...
 1             155     139.5   NA      124     148
 2             NA      139.3   NA      127     156.1
 3             120.6   139.5   131.9   130     159.6
 4             117     139     133.9   135     169.5
 5             NA      138.3   138.7   137.4   169.1
 6             120     138.9   137     139.8   168.4
 7             NA      139.5   135.2   142.1   172.9
 8             119     137.1   135.9   143     176.3
...
```

Can you help me in how to actually run the k-means clustering for the pitch curves?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? For the code? As in `kmeans(data,k=3)`?